# How to setup a Web Hook API URL with Post Method

Tags: api, url, post, webhooks, sandbox

**[image: strong text]**

UIB Sandbox Access request.

The webhook URL will be receiving a webhook payload as an input.

Answer (score 1):

Get the web hook URL from the application you want to send data
use that URL in webhook section of the application you want to receive data from
choose type of events you want to application to notify you about